# Restrict access based on country and user agent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to allow access only to my country(using cloudflare) and user agents (for SEO bots). So actually my country and user agents (for SEO) will have access to allow/index.html, while everybody else is redirected to others.html

I use this in .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^(IT)$


RewriteCond $1 !^(allow)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /allow/index.html [L]

DirectoryIndex others.html


SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*yahoo.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*ask.* search_robot


Allow from env=search_robot
```

I need to know if it is correct especially user agents access.

Comment: You didn't test it, why? I guess it should be `SetEnvIfNoCase ^User-Agent$...`

Comment: I don't know how to test user agents and I need to know if are enough to cover SEO bots. Country blocking works.

Comment: Fair enough. Try modifying as suggested in my previous comment. But, the problem remains if you can't test it.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how to use the code you provide it, maybe you can help me, I found posted solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864727/htaccess-allow-all-from-specific-user-agent

Comment: Good. The modification I suggested is also in the answer in your link. Glad you got a helpful answer anyway.

Comment: I found it, thank you. So in my case will be SetEnvIfNoCase ^User-Agent$ .*(googlebot|yahoobot|bingbot|bot|askbot)

Comment: Why would you want web crawlers from outside your target country to be able to spider your site? That might lead your hidden pages being listed in search engines in countries you don't want seeing them.

Comment: didn't realized that. All I need is for the site to be accessible only from my country and to have a good SEO by letting crawlers access it. I thought that's the solution. What can I do to achieve what I want? Are you saying that my country crawlers are enough for local SEO and other country crawlers have no effect for my site SEO ?

Comment: If the question is closed, please answer it and accept the answer yourself. Or, delete it altogether.