# problems detecting user agent via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, user-agent

I'm using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864727/htaccess-allow-all-from-specific-user-agent) to protect a folder via `.htaccess` and a PHP script.

We use a Google Search Appliance to index this particular protect folder. However, I'm not sure how to allow the crawler through.

To test, I used a firefox addon to fake my user_agent (to `msnbot` in this case) and used the script `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, verifying that `msnbot/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm` was in fact my determined UA.

This is the string of conditionals that authentication script checks against. All of these conditions work,  except the last.

```
current_user_can('edit_posts') || mm_member_decision( array ( "isMember"=>"true", "hasBundle"=>"1", "status" => "active" ) ) || auth_redirect() || ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'msnbot/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)');
```

Comment: so anyone who uses msnbot as their UA can freely access your site? that's not exactly secure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. `|| auth_redirect()` should be last in the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Search Appliance user agent is named `gsa-crawler`.

A full user-agent string might look like this:

```
gsa-crawler (Enterprise; GID09999; name@company.com)
```

https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/help_gsa/crawl_headers

Try to allow that user-agent for a successful crawl.
And because you already figured out, that the user-agent alone is not enough, please add a check for the `id` and/or the `email`.

Comment: thanks for the info. I'm primarily concerned as to whether my syntax is correct: `($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'msnbot/1.1 (+http://search.msn.com/msnbot.htm)')`

Comment: The reason I ask is because now I'm trying to test against my own user_agent and it's still not passing