# Hide cname from search engines

Tags: php, html, web, robots.txt, cname

So I have created a `CNAME` for my domain. e.g.:

```
mycname.domain.com
```

But all URLs withing the `CNAME` show in search engines. How can I prevent these URLs from being crawled? I guess I have to edit the `robots.txt` file but not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Add the restriction in robots.txt so it cannot acces those urls

Comment: That, or filter googlebot user agent & give him 403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, since its a `CNAME` with no physical root folder, you can't really use a `robots.txt`. So you have to do a bit of a work around using `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycname.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /robots-mycname.txt [NC,L]
```

The above rule will redirect the `CNAME` robot to its file so that it does not conflict with your current domain robot file.

Now you create a file called `robots-mycname.txt` with the following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Which means disallow any robot, unhappily not all robots respect the `robots.txt` file so keep that in mind.

---

Another way would be to simple deny requests to that `CNAME` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycname.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

You can also further improve this by setting a specific user-agent like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycname.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

[You can also make a list like this...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864846/342740)

---

[The simplest way to resolve this issue is to add to your pages the canonical tag, you can read more about it here...](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Here in an example of what you would add to your pages in this case:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://main-domain.com/blog/some-page" />
```

However this needs to be done to all the affected pages, if you're using a CMS like WordPress, Drupal, and others, there are plugins to automatically do that for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am a bit confused as to why it's been downvoted? I'm new and it does look correct even if it did have input by others. Downvoting makes this answer look wrong for any future readers...

Comment: This answer is really a good workaround for a dev server as in my case so I really don't see why it was downvoted. +1