# Allow facebook share access images , that are blocked for image hotlinking

Tags: facebook, .htaccess

I have stopped hotlinking of images through htaccess. So when i try to share the post via facebook , i am unable to see the image, It shows blank image.

The htacces code is as follows

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?slidecorner.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?slidecorner.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?facebook.com [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg)$ - [F]
```

If i remove the code , i am able to see the Facebook share image.
Please advise, on how to fix this.

Comment: You need to use [OR] Flag in your conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

You should use the User Agent strings `facebookexternalhit/1.1`, `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` or `Facebot` instead of referrers.

E.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "facebookexternalhit/1.1|facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)|Facebot" [NC]
```

Comment: can you explain in detail , on how how to proceed on this? Please

Comment: as per your advise , i tried the following    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?slidecorner.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?slidecorner.*$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "facebookexternalhit/1.1" [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg)$ - [F]  `   . Now , the image hot-linking doesn't work anymore

Comment: Also , adding the whole code `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "facebookexternalhit/1.1|facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)|Facebot" [NC]` throws errors

Comment: What errors are thrown? You need to be more specific! I'm not an export regarding rewrite rules, but I indicated you which user agents you need to allow access for being able to see the preview images while sharing. Please try to fix this yourself for your setup, as you have given no further details.

Comment: when i add it to htaccess, webpage does not load and throws internal server error

Comment: Well, as we don't know you webserver's configuration, remove the line and start again. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864727/htaccess-allow-all-from-specific-user-agent That's all from me.