# I need to add Woocommerce to my whitelist to allow access to woo mobile app

Tags: .htaccess, woocommerce, whitelist, ip-blocking

A shop website that only works in a specific country by blocking all IPs except that country, so the problem is I need to add woocommerce IP address to the white list to be able to communicate with the shop to see the orders and products.

I blocked it using .htaccess file like this :

```
Order deny,allow 
Deny from all 
Allow from 5.45.128.0/20 
Allow from 37.17.192.0/20 
Allow from 37.123.64.0/18 
Allow from 37.202.64.0/18 
Allow from 37.220.112.0/20
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I blocked it using .htaccess file like this :
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 5.45.128.0/20
Allow from 37.17.192.0/20
Allow from 37.123.64.0/18
Allow from 37.202.64.0/18
Allow from 37.220.112.0/20

Comment: I just need to allow woocommerce using the same way

Comment: Maybe you can allow the APP via the user agent, see: [.htaccess Allow All from Specific User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864846/3730754)